# Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined when trying to emit a document

Tags: reactjs, pouchdb

I am trying to create a `design` for tags of entities in `PouchDB` with `ReactJS`. I managed to save my design using the `put` function, but when I query my design, the response is just an empty array and I am getting following error in console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined
```

I think the problem is in my function that I later use as a map parameter to my design variable:

```
function emitTagsMap(doc)
{
  if (doc !== undefined)
  {
    if (Array.isArray(doc.tags))
    {
       doc.tags.forEach(x =>
       {
          /* Here is probably the problem - this.db is undefined */
          this.db.emit(x, null);
       });
     }
   }
};
```

`this.db` is declared in constructor:

```
constructor(service, name)
{
        if (!service || !name) throw new Error("PouchDatabase initialized incorrectly");
        this.name = name;
        this.db = new PouchDB(name);
        this.service = service;
        this.tagsView();
}
```

Please bare in mind that I am completely new to `PouchDB`.

Any ideas how can I initialize the `emit` function?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you post the code surrounding your emitTagsMap function. Where is this.db declared?

Comment: I added the constructor to the code, thats where this.db is declared

Comment: try to write in this way your method emitTagsMap = (doc) => {....}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call emit over the database object.

Try this:

```
function emitTagsMap(doc)
{
  if (doc !== undefined)
  {
    if (Array.isArray(doc.tags))
    {
       doc.tags.forEach(x =>
       {
          emit(x, null);
       });
     }
   }
};
```

According to the PouchDB docs a design document is formed like this:

```
// first create a new design doc and pass your map function as string into it
var ddoc = {
      _id: "_design/my_index",
      views: {
        by_name: {
         map: "function (doc) {         if (doc !== undefined) {          if (Array.isArray(doc.tags)) {            doc.tags.forEach(x => {              emit(x, null);            });          }        }      }"
        }
      }
    };

// save it
db.put(ddoc).then(function () {
  // success!
}).catch(function (err) {
  // some error (maybe a 409, because it already exists?)
});

//Then you actually query it, by using the name you gave the design document when you saved it:

db.query('my_index/by_name').then(function (res) {
  // got the query results
}).catch(function (err) {
  // some error
});
```

https://pouchdb.com/guides/queries.html

Comment: I want to use my function as a map parameter to the design.

Comment: Please check the lower code sample. Your emit tags map is now part of the design document my_index. If you copy the entire block it should work. You might need to change db.query and db.put to your database.

Comment: this makes the app crash - 'emit' is not defined. Thats why I have been always using this.db.emit with this.db being the instance of PouchDB

Comment: @AdamSulc I updated my answer, please check if it works if the map function is saved as string.

Comment: It works now. Its really weird, I mean if there is .toString() a would expect that it would do the same thing as just putting it in a big string. Thank you

Comment: I think the problem with the .toString() is that the editor does not know that the emit function will be provided by pouch db later. Please accept the answer if you are satisfied with it.

Answer (score 2):

I assume, that your function is a part of a JavaScript class (otherwise you have to explain the idea with `this`). In ES6, you have to bind `this` to your regular functions. You have two options:

First - bind it via constructor:

```
constructor() {
  this.emitTagsMap = this.emitTagsMap.bind(this);
}
```

Second - declare the function as an arrow one. This way, react will bind it for you:

```
emitTagsMap = (doc) =>
{
  if (doc !== undefined)
  {
    if (Array.isArray(doc.tags))
    {
       doc.tags.forEach(x =>
       {
          /* Here is probably the problem - this.db is undefined */
          this.db.emit(x, null);
       });
     }
   }
};
```

Comment: I tried to declare the function as an arrow one, but the compiler wont have it ('(' expected.). Could it be because I have the function defined in a method?

Comment: Since it is a part of a class, you don't need to use the keyword `function`, but declare it as a regular variable. I updated the answer, please have a look.

Comment: should I define it as a const? It behaves really weird, if I have the code same as in your answer then I cant put the emitTagsMap function as a map parameter of my design (its undefined).

Comment: No, you have to define it **inside** your class. And then call it, using `this.emitTagsMap(doc)`

Comment: Unfortunately the console still returns same error for some reason. I really dont understand why though because your solution makes sense to me.

Comment: Make sure that you call the function **after** `this.db` is declared and initialized.

Comment: @AdamSulc are you adding the function to a design doc. After reading the documentation again I'm of the opinion that you don't need this.db for the emit. See here how design docs are implemented: https://pouchdb.com/guides/queries.html

Comment: @JayBee well, but where should I put that? I dont want to use query in my emitTagsMap function and if I put it to foreach its just another parameter, not a function.

Comment: @AdamSulc it is the other way around, you put the emitTagsMap function into the design doc. Then pouch db will call the function whenever you call the view. If you don't want to use design docs you could implement your own map reduce buy using db.AllDocs() and then filtering through all documents.

Comment: @AdamSulc Please check out my answer. If something is not clear I can specify it for you.